# Not able to bypass Run time error 619 in SAP GUI connection

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error, sap-gui

I have a macro to download certain SAP GUI reports to Excel. My issue is that if I run the macro more than once in the same SAP GUI session (first time it works fine), I get this error which I am not able to bypass:

> Run-time error 619

For some reason (I think it's related to which server the user is logged on to), the SAP ERP module (RE-FX) have two different variants/GUIs. Therefore, I have two different setups for downloading the report to Excel depending on the variant/GUI.

I am using the `On Error Goto` statement to shift between those two variants. The Run time error appears in the line following the `On Error Goto` statement.

As mentioned, this works fine the first time I run the macro (no Run Time error occurs and the macro jumps to the error handler as expected), but the second time I run it, the error '619' appears and it is not possible to bypass it.

I have tried the solution in this post (including `Application.Wait`):
[Cannot Bypass Error 619 "Control not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013422/cannot-bypass-error-619-executing-sap-from-vba)

But that did not fix it (it is not the timing which is the issue here).

```
Sub Run_REISCDCF()

 Dim Filepath As String
 Dim ReportDate As String
 Dim SapGuiAuto As Object
 Dim SAPApp As Object
 Dim SAPCon As Object
 Dim session As Object


 Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guide").Cells(5, 5).Text   'place to store SAP reports

'Create connection to SAP
'------------------------------------------
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
'------------------------------------------

'Removed some code to run the report and change layout (which works fine)

'Save to Excel
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_AREA_ROOT:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:0200/subSUB_AREA:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:1000/cntlCC_LIST/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_AREA_ROOT:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:0200/subSUB_AREA:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:1000/cntlCC_LIST/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
    
    On Error GoTo XLSX_variant 'SAP has two different GUI's for RE-FX with one of them only allowing to download to a MHTML file type
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "Filepath" '<-- At this line the Run Time error appears
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "REISCDCF.MHTML"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
Exit Sub

XLSX_variant:
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "Filepath"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "REISCDCF.XLSX"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Could you turn your UPDATE into an answer so that to distinguish question and answers? (you can answer to your own question) Thank you.

Comment: I have now created my update into a separate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
If Not session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]", False) Is Nothing Then

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

End If
```

This code will lookup for the button in the session you are and if it finds it it will click on it else it means it’s not there and I’ll continue with next line.

```
Sub Run_REISCDCF()

 Dim Filepath As String
 Dim ReportDate As String
 Dim SapGuiAuto As Object
 Dim SAPApp As Object
 Dim SAPCon As Object
 Dim session As Object


 Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guide").Cells(5, 5).Text   'place to store SAP reports

'Create connection to SAP
'------------------------------------------
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
'------------------------------------------

'Removed some code to run the report and change layout (which works fine)

'Save to Excel
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_AREA_ROOT:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:0200/subSUB_AREA:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:1000/cntlCC_LIST/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_AREA_ROOT:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:0200/subSUB_AREA:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:1000/cntlCC_LIST/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"

 'SAP has two different GUI's for RE-FX with one of them only allowing to download to a MHTML file type

If Not session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]", False) Is Nothing Then

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

End If

    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "Filepath" '<-- At this line the Run Time error appears
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "REISCDCF.MHTML"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @reFractil for coming up with a solution that worked!
I had to edit his solution slightly in order to embed the two variants (download SAP report as .XLSX or .MHTML), but the structure and code proposed by reFractil is the same:

```
'Changed code only below

'Save to Excel  

    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_AREA_ROOT:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:0200/subSUB_AREA:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:1000/cntlCC_LIST/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_AREA_ROOT:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:0200/subSUB_AREA:SAPLREIS_GUI_CONTROLLER:1000/cntlCC_LIST/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"

'Solution:    

If Not session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]", False) Is Nothing Then 
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Filepath
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "REISCDCF.XLSX" 'Download as .XLSX if in "XLSX SAP_variant"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
    Exit Sub

End If

    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Filepath
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "REISCDCF.MHTML" 'Download as .MHTML if in "MHTML SAP_variant"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
Exit Sub
```